# Clicking on a button or at the current position of mouse using JavaScript to keep Google Colab notebook alive

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-colaboratory, console.log

I am trying to keep the Google Colab notebook alive for few hours even if I go out for some time. People who have no idea should only know that if you don't manually **intervene** then the processes stop and all of your work is lost.

I want my mouse to keep clicking  at the current position  12 hours at an interval of 15 minutes. This would be the best case for me. Also IF I can add  a bit of scroll up and down both  without affecting the position of my mouse would be nice. Obviously, I did nit know how to do that so I went for other options as selectiong an element that is clickable and click it for some time. HAd it been Python and Selenium I would have done it but somehow I could select a position and wrote a code as:

```
run_buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('colab-run-button')

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {setTimeout(() => { run_buttons[run_buttons.length-1].click() ; }, 100);
}
```

Problem is that it is clicking so fast without a time interval. How can I apply Python style `time.sleep()` so that the code inside console click on the button for 12 hours at an interval of 20 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are not waiting for a given *timeout* to complete before queuing next timeout. You will need to properly handle asynchronous behavior of timeouts to accomplish what you want.

Instead, you can use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and notice both of these functions take time in `ms` milliseconds not `s` seconds. `setInterval` calls the given `callback` after specified `ms` ***repeatedly***. So:

```
var keepAliveInterval = setInterval(() => { play_buttons[43].click() ; }, 15 * 60 * 1000); // 15 * 60 * 1000 = 15 minutes in milliseconds
```

To stop this interval, you can have a single timeout of:

```
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(keepAliveInterval) }, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 24 hours in milliseconds
```

Comment: What would the second line of code do? It'll stop the behaviour of the first function?

Comment: You mean `setTimeout`? It will stop the interval after 24 hours. Effectively, stop *keeping alive*. You can ignore this if you want to keep clicking ***indefinitely***.